# error of integer overflow

Tags: c++, integer-overflow

This the part of my OpenGL code, I am getting an error for :

```
struct Ball {
    float x;
    float y;
    float rot;
    float dir;
    bool rmv;
    Ball* next;
};

Ball* curBall;
void addBall() {
    if (balls==NULL) {
        balls=new Ball;
        balls->next=NULL;
        curBall=balls;
    } else {
        curBall->next=new Ball;
        curBall=curBall->next;
        curBall->next=NULL;
    }
    curBall->x=((float)rand()/(float)(RAND_MAX+1))*(ww-1) +1;
    curBall->y=((float)rand()/(float)(RAND_MAX+1))*(wh-1) +1;
    curBall->dir=((float)rand()/(float)(RAND_MAX+1))*(2*PI-1) +1;
    curBall->rot=((float)rand()/(float)(RAND_MAX+1))*(359) +1;
    curBall->rmv=false;
}
```

---

```
error :
In function ‘void addBall()’:
file.cpp:120: warning: integer overflow in expression
file.cpp:121: warning: integer overflow in expression
file.cpp:122: warning: integer overflow in expression
file.cpp:123: warning: integer overflow in expression
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try converting `RAND_MAX` to a float *before* adding to it.

```
curBall->x=((float)rand()/( ((float)RAND_MAX) +1))*(ww-1) +1;
```

et cetera. `RAND_MAX` is often equal to `INT_MAX`, the largest value an integer could hold, thus adding 1 to it while it's still considered an integer pushes it over the integer limit.

Comment: In addition I would suspect that assuming 32 bit float and int,  `(static_cast<float>(RAND_MAX) + 1.0f) == static_cast<float>(RAND_MAX)` because there won't be enough bits available in the float to represent every integer and the addition will just truncate back down.

Comment: I agree that this is the solution, so I'm not going to post my own, but it's worth noting that it appears your two variables dir and rot are in different forms (one in radians, one in degrees).

This might cause you some headaches down the road :) been there, done that!

Comment: it worked.. now i m facing a small problem.. this is a part of game code.. error was in linux but not in windows.. in windows it was working properly but even after i corrected this error linux is just showing me the window.. the game is not running properly.. :(

Comment: In Windows, RAND_MAX is much smaller, I think it's just fifteen bits? 0x7FFF?  Modern Unix-flavored operating systems use 32 bits.  You could try `printf("%d\n", RAND_MAX);` to see what it yields on each of the platforms you're targeting.

Comment: If RAND_MAX *is* 32 bits, the addition of 1 will likely not trigger a roll-over to the next greatest value.  Remember that 32-bit floating point only has 23 bits of mantissa.  You'd need to use doubles.

Comment: but even with double.. it doesn't show me the graphics( implementing moving ball's hitting a target) .. but in windows it does work properly.. Linux i just get the graphics window but no object display :(.. and i need to implement this in linux for my project..

Answer (score 2):

It's probably `RAND_MAX + 1` that's overflowing, since RAND_MAX may well be `== INT_MAX`.

Answer (score 2):

I'd guess your `RAND_MAX` is equal to your `INT_MAX`, so all your `RAND_MAX+1` pieces are overflowing. Since those are both constants, the compiler can detect it at compile time.

Answer (score 2):

It could depend on your compiler if RAND_MAX == MAX_INT then RAND_MAX+1 will overflow.